# How to remove http headers from external server response and pass modified headers to the user (node.js)?

Tags: node.js

I need to remove some headers from external server and pass the response (html page with modified headers) to the client. What secure dependency can this behavior have - it's allowed (i guess proxy servers use it all the time)? And how to do that (doable with express)? Thanks for any directions.

Comment: Are you trying to make your own proxy?

Comment: Nope, just want to remove some X-Frame-Options etc. The simpler the better, but if own proxy will work I would gladly learn how to make one.

Comment: If you're trying to insert yourself between client and server, then that's a proxy.  It is not clear what your network topology is and how you're trying to insert yourself.  Really not sure how you're attempting to do this.  You might be able to just use a pre-built proxy like NGINX.

Comment: client send some data, my serwer (node.js localhost) need to send it to the server. Then If I understand this correctly, external server response to my node.js localhost and then I output this data to the client (router.post res.render). But client need to get the headers changed, so he can for example output the data at iframe and he can't know on what server the data was modified.

Comment: OK, that's just a regular proxy.  NGINX is a pre-built proxy with lots of configurability.  Or, there are various NPM modules for building your own proxy in node.js.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use hijackresponse with no avail. I guess I need to read more about how things are working in node (request.get) and test some more modules before NGINX.